# Nested quotes nightmare : sending an e-mail from a remote host

Tags: ssh, email, quoting

I need to send (from my terminal) an email with attachments from my remote host which I access by ssh.
I already know that to do something remotely, I use

`ssh -p myport myusername@myhost.com "doSomething"`

I also know that to send an e-mail with attachments, I do

`echo "Mail content" | mailx -s "Mail title" -a attachment.txt -S from="myname@gmail" destname@gmail`

So the naive combination of the two would be tosimply replace `doSomething` in the first line
with all of the second line.
This doesn't work, of course, because of the horrendous nested double quotes. 
How to  make this work (and cleanly if possible)? Any help appreciated.

Comment: My typical approach in such cases is to do `ssh sh -c '<shell code goes here>'`.

Comment: Similar: [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567)

Answer (score 7):

For simple cases, you can use single-quotes to protect your command from the local shell, or escape the double-quotes as `\"`.

```
echo "Mail content" | ssh -p myport myusername@myhost.com 'mailx -s "Mail title" -a attachment.txt -S from="myname@gmail" destname@gmail'
# or
echo "Mail content" | ssh -p myport myusername@myhost.com "mailx -s \"Mail title\" -a attachment.txt -S from=\"myname@gmail\" destname@gmail"
```

For more complicated things, the easiest might be to use a heredoc to set a variable:

```
read -r -d '' mailcmd <<'CMD'
echo "quotin'" 'this would be a "nightmare" indeed.' | mailx -s "Anthony's Email" -a attachment.txt -S from="myname@gmail" destname@gmail
CMD
ssh -p myport myusername@myhost.com "$mailcmd"
```

At least in bash, you can ask the shell to quote a variable for you, which may help when you need to do even more annoying things (e.g., chain two `ssh` calls):

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$mailcmd"
echo\ \"quotin\'\"\ \'this\ would\ be\ a\ \"nightmare\"\ indeed.\'\ \|\ mailx\ -s\ \"Anthony\'s\ Email\"\ -a\ attachment.txt\ -S\ from=\"myname@gmail\"\ destname@gmail
```

as you can see, it's automated quoting isn't optimized for fewest backslashes.

### Including local variables

If you need to use a variable in the command, ssh provides a special case that works: ssh can pass environment variables specified by the `SendEnv` option (client) and `AcceptEnv` option (server). If you pass the environment variable, the remote side shell can expand them as normal (and will if you have "$varname" in the here-doc).

Other than that, the easiest way is to omit the quotes on the heredoc, which will let expansions happen (though this means you'll have to escape `$` where you don't want that):

```
$ var1="hello world"
$ read -r -d '' mailcmd <<CMD
echo "$var1" "\$var1"
CMD
$ echo "$mailcmd"
echo "hello world" "$var1"
```

Notice how I'm using `CMD` instead of `'CMD'`; quoting the end marker like that turns off expansion. So by not quoting it, we get expansion. And `"$var1"` gets expanded to `hello world` as expected, but by putting a backslash in front of it the expansion can be avoided. Note that all expansion is enabled, including backtick and `$(…)` expansion. Also note that var1 is just being substituted in; the shell isn't doing any escaping there, so that'd not work if var1 contained a double-quote (etc.). That's one place you can use %q:

```
$ var1='hello "world"'
$ read -r -d '' mailcmd <<CMD
echo $(printf '%q' "$var1") "\$var1"
CMD
$ echo "$mailcmd"
echo hello\ \"world\" "$var1"
```

***A word of warning:** If you're passing data that could conceivably be influenced by an attacker, you must be* very *careful. Any slight mistake in escaping (or different definition of what needs to be escaped between all the shells involved) could become an arbitrary code execution flaw.* It's often easier to build a more robust data passing system than to make sure all the required escaping is present/correct. A *lot* of security vulnerabilities have been escaping failures.

Comment: + 1/2 for `read -r -d` variable, + 1/2 for `printf "%q"`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is almost what I need, which is In fact just  slightly more complicated : the contents of my e-mail command (the thing that you denote by mailcmd) uses previously defined  shell variables. This is probably easy to combine with heredoc or `printf %q`, I tried to guess the correct syntax and failed. Could you please add an example where mailcmd's definition uses a $previouslydefinedvar

Comment: @EwanDelanoy done

Comment: @glennjackman yep, that's the short version of it, but it's more complicated than just that... see the edit, which doubled the answer length...

Comment: Note that this is assuming the login shell of the remote user is Bourne-like (or even `ksh93`/`bash`/`zsh` for the `printf %q` ones) and a compatible character set is used there (if the locale data is not passed along by both ssh and sshd).